# Index out of range when parsing artists

Tags: swift

I have one view controller that displays that should show songs and artists. Whenever I run my code I get an error

> Thread 7: Fatal error: Index out of range for artists. search = songs, artist = artists.

I am trying to get info from 2 tables in my SQL database. I did the same thing as I did for search and It works but now that I added artists I crash. Any help would be appreciated.

Artist.swift:

```
class Artist {

var id = Int()
var name, email: String

init?(id:String, name:String, email:String) {
    self.id = Int(id)!
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
  }
}
```

SearchBarViewController:

```
  func retrieveArtist() {
       let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles/getAlbum.php")
       
       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
           let retrievedList = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        self.parseArtist(data: retrievedList!)
           print(retrievedList!)
           
       }
.resume()
    print("getting artists")
   }

func parseArtist (data: String) {
   if (data.contains("*")) {
       let dataArray = (data as String).split(separator: "*").map(String.init)
       for item in dataArray {
           let itemData = item.split(separator: ",").map(String.init)
           let newArtist = Artist(id: itemData[0], name: itemData[1], email: itemData[2])
           artist.append(newArtist!)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: it seems to me that this line: let newArtist = Artist(id: itemData[0], name: itemData[1], email: itemData[2]). One or more of the indexes you are using is out of range. Meaning when you split the comma delimited line, it is returning less than 3 rows. So for example if your itemData is ['1','Name'] when you try to get itemData[2] is going to be out of range.

Comment: @nick So I have to add a itemData[3]?

Comment: according to your code, you have a list delimited by "*" and each item of that list is delimited by "," so based on your code dataArray looks something like this "1","Name1","Email1" * "2","Name2","Email2" * "3","Name3","Email3" when you split this by * you are going to get:
"1","Name1","Email1"
"2","Name2","Email2"
"3","Name3","Email3"
then when you split each line by "," you are going to get the individual text items. So it seems to me that one for the id,name,email lines does not have all items in it so it might only have id,name

Comment: Yes you were right.